# CSS Background gradient dynamic animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a page with the background gradient animation.

```
<div class="bg-gradient">

</div>

.bg-gradient {
    width: 400px;
    height: 240px;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

I would like to change the colors on page load. But that isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  SetBackgroundColors();
});

function SetBackgroundColors() {
  $('.bg-gradient').css('background', 'linear-gradient(-45deg,' + GetRandomColor() + ',' + GetRandomColor() + ',' + GetRandomColor() + ',' + GetRandomColor() + ')');
}

function GetRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

The colors do change but the animation is not applied.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es13awvc/10/).

Comment: reduce the time on your css from 15s to 5s. I believe it works

Comment: @hamid That did not work.

Comment: you need to reset background-size too, else it goes back to auto auto by default once bg-image is updated  https://jsfiddle.net/dbosnr7m/

Comment: The animation is working fine. The gradient colors are set only once at load time. Thereon in the change in color that you see is due to the animation. Try going down to 1s. The JS is run only the once - perhaps you thought it was supposed to run more than that. Anyway, as it stands the code is fine. Try putting a background-image of an actual image in instead of the linear-gradient and you'll see it moving.

Comment: set only `background-image` instead of `background`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus your suggestion worked. Please post it so that it will be the accepted answer for any other who are experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you update the `background` value, `background-size` is also reset to normal (any short hands value are actually reset) , therefore you also need to reset/specify again its value or only reset `background-image`. ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  SetBackgroundColors();
});

function SetBackgroundColors() {
  $('.bg-gradient').css('background', 'linear-gradient(-45deg,' + GetRandomColor() + ',' + GetRandomColor() + ',' + GetRandomColor() + ',' + GetRandomColor() + ')').css('background-size', '400% 400%');
}

function GetRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
.bg-gradient {
    width: 400px;
    height: 240px;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-gradient">

</div>
```